# how to modify /etc/hosts from shell scripts?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bash, cron, hosts-file

I need to change some `hosts` entries - for example, there's a desire to update `hosts` to have `active.vm` host match the IP of currently booted VM (with some testing appliance). Guest software within VM reports machine's address back to host, and I need to update /etc/hosts based on that information - there's always some time for writing another daemon/cronjob, but wanted to use something existing for fixing `hosts` entries with a dumb syntax of `hostname current_ip`.

Someone had recommended me the `bind-tools` package, but - its `nsupdate`|`host` don't suit the task at all. ..

*Upd: still looking for something from bind suite, but at least dynamic regeneration seems to be the best solution, and augtool is nice too.*

*Upd: due to my laziness, dynamic regeneration is not planned to use right now, so started using augtool at the cronjob, that reads webserver's access logs for latest IP - at the VMs which run Windows, whole monitoring solution is just a webbrowser which loads specific url from host machine and has a small reload interval*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at [augeas](http://augeas.net/). It has a ready-made parser/serializer for the hosts file (that's even in their quick tour guide) and comes with a simple tool to make changes (augtool).

Comment: hm, it's in Gentoo portage tree, so will try it.. but somehow I feel that syntax of `augtool> set /files/etc/hosts/*[alias[1] = 'active.vm']/ipaddr 1.1.1.1` will not be tolerated by it. Will test..

Comment: it actually worked, but had to use `alias =` instead of addressing `alias[1]` or `alias[2]`.. it didn't supported them, so editing the entry by other than first name was impossible (not a problem, but will ask for a correct syntax on a list)

Comment: When you use `alias` in this expression, it matches *any* `alias` subnode, not just the firs the first one.

Comment: there's even a `brew` for it.

Answer (score 11):

I'd rather not touch `/etc/hosts` in terms of parsing and such. I'd simply create a directory called `/etc/hosts.d/` and make up some script that takes:

- ip
- name
- aliases

creates one (1) file with one (1) line. The filename will be `<ip>.host` and then `cat /etc/hosts.d/*host > /tmp/hosts.new && mv /tmp/hosts.new /etc/hosts`. Maybe add an `incron` event that watches the `/etc/hosts.d/` directory and regenerates `/etc/hosts` whenever something happens, that way you'll get rid of old entries too.

Comment: it's a very nice idea, with complete regeneration, sir - at least it saves from having empty hosts file